# Make SVG icons appear on JS to do list item

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I am trying to create a to do list. Each item which is an li element has two SVG icons. At this point, when you type in text in the input field and click the plus button next to it, a li element appears but no SVG icons appear. How do i make the SVG icons appear each time I add a new item to the to do list?

```js
/*var removeSVG = svgElementFromString('<svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" id="removeB" class="removeB" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 328.51 328.51" style="enable-background:new 0 0 328.51 328.51;" xml:space="preserve"><polygon points="229.044,88.858 164.255,153.647 99.466,88.858 88.858,99.466 153.647,164.255 88.858,229.044 99.466,239.651 
   164.255,174.862 229.044,239.651 239.651,229.044 174.862,164.255 239.651,99.466   "/> </svg>');*/


document.getElementById('button-plus').addEventListener('click', function(){
  var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
  if(value) addItem(value);
});
function addItem(text){
  var list = document.getElementById('to-do');
  
  item = document.createElement("li");
  item.innerText = text;
  var buttons = document.createElement('div');
  buttons.classList.add('buttons');
  
  var remove = document.createElement('button');
  remove.classList.add('remove');
  //remove.innerHTML = removeSVG;
  
  var complete = document.createElement('button');
  complete.classList.add('complete');
  //complete.innerHTML = completeSVG;
  
  buttons.appendChild(remove);
  buttons.appendChild(complete);
  item.appendChild(buttons);

  list.appendChild(item);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: rgb(162, 193, 60);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(159, 160, 155);
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

header input {
 appearance: none;
 text-indent: 10px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
 border-top-right-radius: 25px;
 border-top-left-radius: 12px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
 width: 100%;
 background: rgb(233, 255, 170);
 height: 45px;
 font-family: Century Gothic;
 border: none;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding-right: 60px;
}

header button {
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 13.5px;
height: 43px;
width: 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
border-top-right-radius: 25px;
appearance: none;
border: none;
background: rgb(238, 255, 173);
border-left: 2px solid rgb(162, 193, 60);
cursor: pointer;
}

button svg {
z-index: 6;
position: absolute;
border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
border-top-right-radius: 25px;
right: 0;
top: -1px;
}/*
.container{
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}*/
 .to-do {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   padding: 0;
  /*border: 1px lid black;*/
}
.to-do li{
  width: 85%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(159, 160, 155, 0.5);
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  padding: 0 105px 0 25px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
}
.to-do li .buttons{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
}
.to-do li .buttons button{
  appearance: none;
  width: 47.5px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.to-do li .buttons button:last-of-type:before{
  content: '';
  width: 0.8px;
  height: 29px;
  background: gray;
  opacity: 0.4;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -6px;
}/*
.to-do li button:nth-child(1):hover .x-fill{
  fill: red;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.to-do li button:nth-child(2):hover .tick-fill{
  fill: orange;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}*/
.complete svg{
  fill: green;
}
.complete svg:hover{
  fill: orange;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.remove svg{
  fill: gray;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.remove svg:hover{
  fill: red;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<head>

<title>To do List App</title>

</head>
<body>
<header>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Next on my to do list is...." id="input">
  <button id="button-plus">
 <svg width="48" height="43" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect fill="#0186b2" height="28" id="svg_1" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="5" width="4" x="19.5" y="8.5"/>
  <rect fill="#47bcbc" height="3" id="svg_2" stroke="#000000" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="5" width="28" x="7.5" y="20.5"/>
</svg>
   
    </svg>
  </button>
</header>
  <div class="container">
<ul id="to-do" class="to-do">
  <li>First to do <div class="buttons">
    <button class="remove"><!--<svg width="45" height="50" id="delete-button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect fill="gray" height="28.44763" class="x-fill" id="svg_1" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="5" transform="rotate(39.2894 22.2822 26.8218)" width="1.49252" x="21.53592" y="12.59797"/>
  <rect fill="gray" height="30.65491" class="x-fill" id="svg_2" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="5" transform="rotate(-45.1764 22.3317 26.664)" width="1.70493" x="21.47928" y="11.33651"/>
</svg>-->
     <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" id="removeB" class="removeB" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 328.51 328.51" style="enable-background:new 0 0 328.51 328.51;" xml:space="preserve">
  <polygon points="229.044,88.858 164.255,153.647 99.466,88.858 88.858,99.466 153.647,164.255 88.858,229.044 99.466,239.651 
   164.255,174.862 229.044,239.651 239.651,229.044 174.862,164.255 239.651,99.466   "/>
      </svg>
    </button>
    <button class="complete"><!--<svg width="45" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <rect fill="#21b221" height="28.44763" class="tick-fill" id="svg_1" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="5" transform="rotate(39.2894 24.2822 25.8218)" width="1.49252" x="23.53592" y="11.59797"/>
  <rect fill="#21b221" height="12.26151" class="tick-fill" id="svg_2" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="5" transform="rotate(-45.1764 11.8548 33.147)" width="1.70493" x="11.00232" y="27.0162"/>
</svg>-->
    <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 52 52" style="enable-background:new 0 0 52 52;" xml:space="preserve">
 
 <path d="M38.252,15.336l-15.369,17.29l-9.259-7.407c-0.43-0.345-1.061-0.274-1.405,0.156c-0.345,0.432-0.275,1.061,0.156,1.406
  l10,8C22.559,34.928,22.78,35,23,35c0.276,0,0.551-0.114,0.748-0.336l16-18c0.367-0.412,0.33-1.045-0.083-1.411
  C39.251,14.885,38.62,14.922,38.252,15.336z"/>
  </svg>
    </button>
    </div></li>
  </ul>
    <ul id="completed" class="completed">
      
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way to do this. Javascript offers the powerful **cloneNode()** method which clones an entire element including all it's children. You don't need to manually recreate the structure of your to-do box.

Usage is simple: Give the element you want to clone - `li` - an id e.g. **master** and change your **addItem()** function to this:

```
function addItem(text){
  var list = document.getElementById('to-do');
  var item = document.getElementById("master").cloneNode(true);
  item.removeAttribute("id");
  item.firstChild.data=text;
  list.appendChild(item);
}
```

Cloning really means cloning so the cloned element would share the same id as the original that's why we have to remove the id from the clone.

Here's an example:

```js
document.getElementById('button-plus').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var value = document.getElementById('input').value;
  if (value) addItem(value);
});

function addItem(text) {
  var list = document.getElementById('to-do');
  var item = document.getElementById("master").cloneNode(true);
  item.removeAttribute("id");
  item.firstChild.data = text;
  list.appendChild(item);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background: rgb(162, 193, 60);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(159, 160, 155);
  padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

header input {
  appearance: none;
  text-indent: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 12px;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgb(233, 255, 170);
  height: 45px;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-right: 60px;
}

header button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 13.5px;
  height: 43px;
  width: 50px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  appearance: none;
  border: none;
  background: rgb(238, 255, 173);
  border-left: 2px solid rgb(162, 193, 60);
  cursor: pointer;
}

button svg {
  z-index: 6;
  position: absolute;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
  border-top-right-radius: 25px;
  right: 0;
  top: -1px;
}


/*
.container{
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}*/

.to-do {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  list-style-type: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  /*border: 1px lid black;*/
}

.to-do li {
  width: 85%;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgb(159, 160, 155, 0.5);
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Century Gothic;
  padding: 0 105px 0 25px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.to-do li .buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
}

.to-do li .buttons button {
  appearance: none;
  width: 47.5px;
  height: 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.to-do li .buttons button:last-of-type:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0.8px;
  height: 29px;
  background: gray;
  opacity: 0.4;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -6px;
}


/*
.to-do li button:nth-child(1):hover .x-fill{
  fill: red;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.to-do li button:nth-child(2):hover .tick-fill{
  fill: orange;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}*/

.complete svg {
  fill: green;
}

.complete svg:hover {
  fill: orange;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}

.remove svg {
  fill: gray;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.remove svg:hover {
  fill: red;
  opacity: 0.7;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<head>

  <title>To do List App</title>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Next on my to do list is...." id="input">
    <button id="button-plus">
 <svg width="48" height="43" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect fill="#0186b2" height="28" id="svg_1" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="5" width="4" x="19.5" y="8.5"/>
  <rect fill="#47bcbc" height="3" id="svg_2" stroke="#000000" stroke-dasharray="null" stroke-linecap="null" stroke-linejoin="null" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="5" width="28" x="7.5" y="20.5"/>
</svg>
   
    </svg>
  </button>
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <ul id="to-do" class="to-do">
      <li id="master">First to do
        <div class="buttons">
          <button class="remove"><!--<svg width="45" height="50" id="delete-button" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect fill="gray" height="28.44763" class="x-fill" id="svg_1" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="5" transform="rotate(39.2894 22.2822 26.8218)" width="1.49252" x="21.53592" y="12.59797"/>
  <rect fill="gray" height="30.65491" class="x-fill" id="svg_2" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="5" transform="rotate(-45.1764 22.3317 26.664)" width="1.70493" x="21.47928" y="11.33651"/>
</svg>-->
     <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" id="removeB" class="removeB" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 328.51 328.51" style="enable-background:new 0 0 328.51 328.51;" xml:space="preserve">
  <polygon points="229.044,88.858 164.255,153.647 99.466,88.858 88.858,99.466 153.647,164.255 88.858,229.044 99.466,239.651 
   164.255,174.862 229.044,239.651 239.651,229.044 174.862,164.255 239.651,99.466   "/>
      </svg>
    </button>
          <button class="complete"><!--<svg width="45" height="50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
   <rect fill="#21b221" height="28.44763" class="tick-fill" id="svg_1" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="5" transform="rotate(39.2894 24.2822 25.8218)" width="1.49252" x="23.53592" y="11.59797"/>
  <rect fill="#21b221" height="12.26151" class="tick-fill" id="svg_2" stroke="#000000" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="5" transform="rotate(-45.1764 11.8548 33.147)" width="1.70493" x="11.00232" y="27.0162"/>
</svg>-->
    <svg version="1.1" id="Capa_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
  viewBox="0 0 52 52" style="enable-background:new 0 0 52 52;" xml:space="preserve">
 
 <path d="M38.252,15.336l-15.369,17.29l-9.259-7.407c-0.43-0.345-1.061-0.274-1.405,0.156c-0.345,0.432-0.275,1.061,0.156,1.406
  l10,8C22.559,34.928,22.78,35,23,35c0.276,0,0.551-0.114,0.748-0.336l16-18c0.367-0.412,0.33-1.045-0.083-1.411
  C39.251,14.885,38.62,14.922,38.252,15.336z"/>
  </svg>
    </button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="completed" class="completed">

    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
```